# The Consonant Eater

Tags: wordplay

The consonant eater eats consonants from words, leaving only vowels (AEIOUY).

Can you find words to fit these empty shells?

> U _ E _ I _ _ E
>
> I _ A U _ I _ _ E
>
> _ E _ A _ A _ E _ Y
>
> _ E _ E _ _ A _ I O _
>
> _ O _ _ E _ _ A _ O _ Y

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mostly answered, the first might be wrong.

U _ E _ I _ _ E

> UNEDIBLE

I _ A U _ I _ _ E

> INAUDIBLE

_ E _ A _ A _ E _ Y

> SEPARATELY

_ E _ E _ _ A _ I O _

> CELEBRATION 
>  I think there are multiple answers to this one, other possibilities are 
>  DESECRATION 
>  PENETRATION 
>  RESERVATION

_ O _ _ E _ _ A _ O _ Y

> CONSERVATORY 
>  also has other answers such as 
>  COMPENSATORY 
>  CONSECRATORY

Comment: Popped the first one into a crossword solver. Checks out.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one start with 'IN' and not 'UN'? my dictionary seems to indicate so.

Answer (score 4):

The first two words:

> They seem to end in -IBLE and I came up with:
>  UNEDIBLE and INAUDIBLE

The third one:

> This seems to be an adjective as well (-ELY):
>  SEPARATELY

The fourth one:

> A noun ending in -ION, e.g.:
>  DELECTATION

And the last one:

> Another adjective, ending in -ATORY, e.g.:
>  COMPENSATORY
>  COMPELLATORY

*NOTE:* Having found the first two words, I was hoping for the other words to be ...

> U _ _ E E A _ _ E
>  I _ _ A _ _ I _ _ E
>  I _ O _ O _ O U _

Comment: Unseeable, intangible and inodorous?  (Is "inodorous" a word?)

Comment: Exactly! :) Yes, I believe [inodorous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inodorous) is a word.